# How to create an index that is both string and number for a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to create a column just like this:

[image]

İn Excel this can be done easily where the remaining rows can be auto-filled. How to achieve the same in python using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `f-string`s with zero fill values:

```
df['new'] = [f'abc_{n+1:02}' for n in range(len(df))]
```

If default index is possible add `1`, convert to strings and add [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['new'] = 'abc_' + (df.index + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```